# collect all xpath results into an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, tags, automation, watir

I have a very poorly coded JSP that I am trying to run automation on.  There are a series of checkboxes with names (no IDs) of "delete[x]" where X is the item number of the item populated.  I am trying to select all the checkboxes so I can delete every entry.  Here is what I have

```
check_boxes = []
check_boxes.push(@browser.checkbox(:xpath, "//input[contains(@name,'delete')]"))
puts check_boxes.size

check_boxes.each do |check_box|
check_box.set
```

The problem with this is it only selects the first instance (node) that matches the xpath to dump into the array.  I know I can iterate through the xpath adding an index to the node, and then put a rescue in that drops me out when the index goes out of bounds, but that seems like the dirty way to do it.

I know there is an "as" tag that gets a set of anchors and i was wondering if there was a method like that for taking the whole selection of checkboxes

Comment: They return the first element of the result set.  You can append it by adding an index to the end of the xpath, but you still only get 1 result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the xpath itself. It is the `@browser.checkbox` that is causing only the first checkbox to be returned.

If you want all matching checkboxes, you should use (notice the plural):

```
@browser.checkboxes
```

Note that `checkboxes` returns a collection of checkboxes. Unless you are doing something really fancy, you usually do not need to convert it to an array.

You can simply do:

```
@browser.checkboxes(:name => /delete/).each do |checkbox|
  checkbox.set
end
```

Comment: gotta love the dynamic language of ruby